# JPA, JSF and should my entity still be managed?

Tags: java, jpa, jsf, cdi

I have a set of parent / child database tables and what I want to happen is

- List of parent objects are displayed to user in datatable
- User clicks button on row to create child record for that row

I have this working but at the point I come to persist the data I am merging as the object is not managed.   I am not sure whether this is because I am missing something fundamental and the object shouldn't be managed or whether I have done something wrong in the code.

### POJOs

```java
@Entity
public class Foo {
  @Id
  @Column(name="FOO_ID)
  private int id;
  
  @Column(name="FOO_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Bar> bars;

  private void addBar(Bar bar) {
    bars.add(bar);
    bar.setFoo(this);
  }
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
  @Id
  @Column(name="BAR_ID")
  private it id;
  
  @Column(name="BAR_NAME")
  private String name;
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
  private Foo foo;
}
```

### DAOService

```java
@RequestScoped
@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class DAOService {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa-pu")
  private EntityManager entityMgr;

  public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    TypedQuery<Foo> fooQuery = entityMgr.createQuery("select f from Foo ...", Foo.class);
    return fooQuery.setParameter("param", "value").getResultList();
  }

  public void processFoo(Foo foo) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setName("Test");
    foo.addBar(bar);
    entityMgr.merge(foo); // Don't think this should be merge
  }
  // more stuff
}
```

### Backing Bean

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  @Inject
  private DAOService dao;
  
  private List<Foo> foos;
  private Foo selectedFoo;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    foos = dao.getFoos();
  }

  public void processFoo() {
    dao.processFoo(selectedFoo);
  }
}
```

### JSF

```xml
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="dt" value="#{myBean.bars}" var="bar">
    <p:column headerText="id">
      <h:outputText value="#{foo.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name">
      <h:outputText value="#{foo.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
      <p:commandButton value="here" action="#{myBean.processFoo}" update=":form:dt">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{foo}" target="#{myBean.selectedFoo}" />
      </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

### Problem

My understanding is that I shouldn't really be needing to merge `foo` back as it originated from the entityMgr query but adding a check for `entityMgr.contains(foo)` into the DAOService code says it is not managed.

This is working using the merge but I worried I have missed something fundamental and I am just hiding the real problem by calling merge.

---

### Update

OK this does appear to be my lack of understanding.   I hadn't appreciated that the persistence cache would only last as long as a transaction so as soon as the code to return the objects had completed, the objects would have been disconnected.

Changing the DAOService to `@Stateful` and changing the `PersistenceContextType` to extended does mean the objects are still in cache when I am processing the update.   Everything I can find about EXTENDED suggests you should be wary of it but it is useful in certain situations but nothing seems to elaborate on what those situations are...

So I guess the fundamental question still exists, should my objects be managed?   Is there anything wrong with the original approach and disconnecting the objects and merging them after update (the only impact is extra database queries to get the current record at merge time?)

Comment: I didn't use JSF in a while but if I remember correctly backing beans are not transactional and thus any entities sent to a backing bean will become detached. This is due to the first level cache basically being bound to the transaction life cycle (in Hibernate via its session) and once the transaction ends that cache is evicted and thus any entities in it become detached. You could try long-running sessions that can span multiple transactions but that's normally not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is, that JPA manages **instances**, and as your entities travel down to the JSF layer and return, they got converted into different instances, which are not managed by JPA...